# Addition of two lists in C

Tags: c, list

I need help. I want to add two lists together (sum of two lists).

The idea is to take two list of elements and I need to have the sum of those two list. the answer should be an integer (int).

Here are my codes:

```
typedef struct element element;
struct element {
  int val;
  struct element *nxt;
};


enum { STOCK_MEM = 1024};

struct element memoire[STOCK_MEM];

typedef element* llist;

void init_memoire() {
  int i;
   for(i = 0; i < STOCK_MEM; i++)
    memoire[i].val = -2;
}

llist consDebut(llist liste, int valeur) {
  element* newEl = malloc(sizeof(element));
  newEl->val = valeur;
  newEl->nxt = liste;
  return newEl;
}

//Ajouter un élément en fin de la liste
llist consFin(llist liste, int valeur) {
  element* newEl = malloc(sizeof(element));
  newEl->val = valeur;
  newEl->nxt = NULL;
  if(liste == NULL) {
    return newEl;
  } else {
    element* temp = liste;
    while(temp->nxt != NULL) {
      temp = temp->nxt;
    }
    temp->nxt = newEl;
    return liste;
  }
}


int estVide(llist liste) {
  if(liste == NULL) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

int main() {
  init_memoire();
  llist newlist = NULL;
  int i;
  for(i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
    newlist = consDebut(newlist, i);
    newlist = consFin(newlist, i);
  }


  llist list2 = NULL;
  int c;
  for(c = 1; c <= 5; c++) {
    list2 = consDebut(list2, c);
  }
return 0;
}
```

Can somebody help please

Comment: Just parse the lists. You know how (see `consFin`).

Comment: What is the purpose of `memoire`? You never use it beyond initialisation.

Comment: Your hour would be better spent on actual debugging rather than posting questions on here.

Answer (score 0):

you can checkout this link for code you can use to do it:
http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/add-two-numbers-represented-by-linked-lists/

and as you need represent sum in integer you can do it by saving right most number in the integer variable and then whenever some other element come you can do variable=10^i+variable, where i represent ten places like i=1 for 10, i=2 for 100 and so on.